# Deleting from Multiple Select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I need to delete an item from a multiple list using jQuery

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="theCheckbox"/>
<select id="theSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#theCheckbox").change(function() {
    $("#theSelect").attr("multiple", (this.checked) ? "multiple" : "");
}).change();
```

[This is the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/DdhSF/161/)

This is my code form my project. if you can implement on this code i will be glad! 
[My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/WCPue/15/)

Comment: What is your problem? What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? Please don't become a "fire and forget"-cannon ;)

Comment: what is the question ???

Answer (score 2):

Just select the option you want to delete and call the `remove()` function on it:

```
$('#theSelect option:eq(1)').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DdhSF/162/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WCPue/15/ This is my example from my project , if you can take a look on that and help me to delete elements from the list, the framework is 1.8

Comment: @OfirAttia If you are using jQuery 1.8 then why have you selected 1.6 on jsfiddle? Also, how do you actually want to delete the items?

Comment: i can limit the clicks? because in my code i can pick "img" anytime i want. there is option to limit it? one click?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Multiple Select list [see this Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/DdhSF/166/)

Both Condition Work.

```
$("#theCheckbox").change(function() {
    $("#theSelect").attr("multiple", (this.checked) ? "multiple" : "");
}).change();

$('a').click(function() {
    $('#theSelect option:selected').remove();
});
```

Comment: look at this one : http://jsfiddle.net/WCPue/22/ there is an option to limit the clicks? to avoid duplicates. and one more thing, if you can see its multiple list but only 2 rows can be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#theSelect').change(function(){
    var selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    //alert(selectedIndex);
    var selected = $(this).children("option").eq(selectedIndex);
    selected.remove();
});
$("#theCheckbox").change(function() {
    $("#theSelect").attr("multiple", (this.checked) ? "multiple" : "");
}).change();​
```